# NFC type B PUPI doubts

Tags: tags, arduino, nfc

I have the Panasonic MN63Y1210 tag. I have read it with different phones and always I see that the ID is `0x00000000`

I've made a program with Arduino and Adafruit's PN532 shield and I have that response too, in ATQB, the PUPI appears like `0x00000000`, but when I read the ISO 14443-3 I read this:

> A Pseudo-Unique Identifier (PUPI) is used to differenciate PICCs
>   during anticollision. This 4-byte number may be either a number
>   dinamically generated by the PICC or a diversified fixed number. The
>   PUPI shall only be generated by a state transition form the POWER-OFF
>   to the IDLE state.

For the transition from **POWER OFF** to **IDLE**, we need a field, so, I expect that when I try to read the tag this is not in **POWER OFF**, because I'm applying a field, but I think it is strange to have that PUPI of `0x00000000`. I've tested with another tag (same Panasonic model) and I get the same PUPI...

Is this normal? Or what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start by looking into the [datasheet of the MN63Y1210](http://www.semicon.panasonic.co.jp/ds4/MN63Y1210_E.pdf):

On page 26 (table 3-13) you will find that the default value this chip uses for the PUPI is `00000000`. You can configure that value, for instance, over the serial interface.